# curl --output append to a file (without >> redirection)

Tags: bash

Is there a way for curl to append output to an existing file using --output/-o option without overwriting it?
I cannot use redirection:

```
curl http://url >> file
```

Because I am using a return code from curl:

```
response="$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output file http://url)"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Give process substitution a try.

```
curl --output >(cat >> file) http://url
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears not. You can write to a temp file and then append to your actual output file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
trap "rm $tmp" EXIT

response=$(curl --output "$tmp" ...)

cat "$tmp" >> output.file
```